# Python openpyxl Package defined_names Does Not Recognize Named Ranges

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I have an existing workbook that I need to modify with openpyxl.  The workbook contains tables that are sources to pivot tables.  I have assigned names to the tables in the Name Manager in Excel.  I would like to access those ranges in openpyxl to replace the data with updated info, but openpyxl does not seem to recognize the existing ranges.

I have followed the code found in the documentation on [the openpyxl site](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/defined_names.html) without success.  Even when I successfully follow the instructions to create a named range (which is not what I really want to do - I want to access existing named ranges), the newly created named range only lasts while the file is open and does not persist when saving the file.

I have checked to be sure that the scope of each named range is "Workbook" and `ws._tables[0].name` gives me the correct name of the table, but I have not been successful in figuring out how to manipulate the data in it or determine how many rows/columns, etc. it contains so that I can replace the data in it.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(args.xlfile)
try:
    source_cm = wb.defined_names['tblAcq']
except KeyError as e:
    print(e)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Tables are not stored as definedNames.

Answer (score 1):

I am not experiencing the same issues you are having. Using the [defined_name](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.html) module, I am able to create, save, and access named ranges within my Excel sheet.

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import *
from openpyxl.styles import NamedStyle

wb = load_workbook("document.xlsx")
ws = wb.active
#new_range = openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.DefinedName('newrange', attr_text='Sheet!$B$1:$B$5') 
#wb.defined_names.append(new_range)
print(wb.defined_names.get('newrange'))
wb.save('document.xlsx')
```

After saving my document with the new named range, I `get()` the `defined_names` in the workbook using `print(wb.defined_names.get('newrange'))`

**outputs**

```py
<openpyxl.workbook.defined_name.DefinedName object>
Parameters:
name='newrange', comment=None, customMenu=None, description=None, help=None, statusBar=None, localSheetId=None, hidden=None, function=None, vbProcedure=None, xlm=None, functionGroupId=None, shortcutKey=None, publishToServer=None, workbookParameter=None, attr_text='Sheet!$B$1:$B$5'
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with Excel tables using openpyxl find them in a worksheet object, and it cannot be opened as read only. They can't be found in `defined_name` like other named ranges. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/worksheet_tables.html

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

wb = load_workbook(args.xlfile, read_only=False)
ws = wb['my_sheet_name']
source_cm = ws.tables['tblAcq']
```

To see all table names in a WorkSheet: `ws.tables.items()`